# How to change color of "like button" for individual posts in template using JQuery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django/stackoverflow and have been learning most from here and google.

I want to create a like button that changes color and submits .form through POST without having to **refresh/reload** the template/page. Forgive me if I'm asking the question improperly, it took me a while to try and phrase the question best I could.

I'm looking at JQuery/AJAX examples that provide similar answers, but all consist of single Object within a template(blog.html). Since I have multiple Posts(objects) from multiple Users, when applying an AJAX call and using **id="like-btn"**, only the First Object Button changes color.

So I found an answer where, instead of using **id="like-btn"**; which only updates the first Object button, using **class="like-btn"** updates all Posts(objects). So now when the "like-btn" is clicked, all "like-btn" from all Posts change as they are a class.

Now I'm stuck between updating only the First Post Button(id="like-btn") or updating All Post Buttons(class="like-btn").

Any ideas on how to only update the clicked "like-btn" ?

```html
'''template blog.html'''

<form action="/blog/" method="POST" class="post-form">\ {% csrf_token %}

  <button class="hoverable" type="submit">

       <i class="like-btn material-icons">check_box</i>

   </button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".like-btn").click(function() {

      $(".like-btn").css("color", "red");

      $(".like-btn").css("background-color", "transparent");

    });

  });
</script>
```

This result will update all "like-btn"'s in the template, instead of only updating the clicked "like-btn"

Comment: You need to show the rest of the template. How do you have multiple buttons?

Comment: you can use `$(this)` to change the colour of the clicked item. something like `$(this).css("color", "red");`

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I would love to show the entire template, but it's intricate and would entail I should have to post the view as well.
I have two forms in a single Users Post; one for commenting and one for liking. They share the same form but are separate submissions.

Comment: @Nalin Dobhal it worked! holy moly..I feel dumb. Thank you!